# Adapting a layout using a Dialog Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, dialog, fragment

I'm trying to adapt a layout in a dialog fragment to show an imageview, a text view and two butttons, but I have problem adapting the layout in it.

I get this:

http://kitsord.com/imagestack/Screenshot_2014-05-22-11-35-22.png

And the output should look something like this:

http://kitsord.com/imagestack/looks.png

So I don't know why the text and the buttons don't show correctly.

**The DialogFragment is this one:**

```
  public class LearnFragment extends DialogFragment {
    ImageView imgC;
    VideoView myVideoView;
    View root ;
    TextView textv ;
    ImageButton next , atras;
    Integer contador;

    public static LearnFragment newInstance() {
        LearnFragment f = new LearnFragment();
        return f;
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        contador = GridViewFragmet.positionarchivo; // this is a static variable from another class

        if (getDialog() != null) {
            getDialog().getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            getDialog().getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
        }

         LayoutInflater inflaterr = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
         root = inflaterr.inflate(R.layout.aprender_fragment_display, null);
         myVideoView = (VideoView)root.findViewById(R.id.videos_aprender);
         imgC =(ImageView) root.findViewById(R.id.imagenes_aprender);
         textv = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.text_aprender);
         next = (ImageButton) root.findViewById(R.id.btnnext_aprender);
         atras = (ImageButton) root.findViewById(R.id.btnatras_aprender);

         myVideoView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
         imgC.setVisibility(View.GONE);
         textv.setVisibility(-1);

         if(contador == 0) {
             atras.setVisibility(-1);
         } else if(contador > 0 && contador < LearnAdapter.imagenesAprender.size() - 1){

             next.setVisibility(0);
             atras.setVisibility(0);

         } else if(contador == LearnAdapter.imagenesAprender.size() - 1) {
             next.setVisibility(-1);
         }

         startIt(GridViewFragmet.nombrearchivo);

         next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(View view){
                    myVideoView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    imgC.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    textv.setVisibility(-1);
                    if(contador + 1 < LearnAdapter.imagenesAprender.size()){
                        ++contador;
                        startIt(LearnAdapter.imagenesAprender.get(contador));
                        atras.setVisibility(0);
                        if(contador == LearnAdapter.imagenesAprender.size() - 1){
                             next.setVisibility(-1);
                        }
                    }
                }
          });

         atras.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){            
                public void onClick(View view){
                    myVideoView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    imgC.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    textv.setVisibility(-1);
                    if(contador - 1 >= 0){
                        --contador; 
                        startIt(LearnAdapter.imagenesAprender.get(contador));
                         next.setVisibility(0);
                         if(contador == 0) {
                             atras.setVisibility(-1);
                         }
                    }
                }
          });

        return root;
    }

    public void startIt(String archivo){

        if(archivo.substring(archivo.lastIndexOf(".") + 1).equals(variablesGlobales.IMAGENES.obtenerinfo())) {

             textv.setVisibility(0);
             textv.setText(archivo.substring(archivo.lastIndexOf("/")+1, archivo.lastIndexOf(".")));
             imgC.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

             Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(archivo);
             imgC.setImageBitmap(bmp);

         } else {

             textv.setVisibility(0);
             textv.setText(archivo.substring(archivo.lastIndexOf("/")+1, archivo.lastIndexOf(".")));
             myVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    mp.setLooping(true);
                }
            });  

             myVideoView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
             myVideoView.setZOrderOnTop(true);
             myVideoView.setVideoPath(archivo);                                     
             myVideoView.start();

         }

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        // change dialog width
        if (getDialog() != null) {

            int fullWidth = getDialog().getWindow().getAttributes().width;

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {
                Display display = getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
                Point size = new Point();
                display.getSize(size);
                fullWidth = size.x;
            } else {
                Display display = getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
                fullWidth = display.getWidth();
            }

            final int padding = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 24, getResources()
                    .getDisplayMetrics());

            int w = fullWidth - padding;
            int h = getDialog().getWindow().getAttributes().height;

            getDialog().getWindow().setLayout(w, h);

        }
    }

}
```

**The layout is this one:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical" >

   <LinearLayout
       android:id="@+id/ll1"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_weight="1" >

       <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <VideoView
            android:id="@+id/videos_aprender"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imagenes_aprender"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:src="@drawable/abc" />

    </RelativeLayout>

   </LinearLayout>

   <LinearLayout
       android:id="@+id/ll2"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_weight="0.4"
       android:orientation="horizontal" >

       <LinearLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:orientation="vertical" 
           android:layout_weight="1">

           <TextView
               android:id="@+id/text_aprender"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:layout_gravity="center"
               android:background="#0f9f9f"
               android:gravity="center"
               android:text="Large Text"
               android:textAlignment="center"
               android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
               android:textColor="#fff"
               android:textSize="25dp" />

       </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

   <LinearLayout
       android:id="@+id/ll3"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_weight="0.8" >

       <LinearLayout
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:orientation="vertical"
           android:layout_weight="1" >

           <ImageButton
               android:id="@+id/btnatras_aprender"
               style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
               android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
               android:background="#00FFFFFF"
               android:src="@drawable/arrow_izq"  />

       </LinearLayout>

       <LinearLayout
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:orientation="vertical" 
           android:layout_weight="0.9">

           <ImageButton
               android:id="@+id/btnnext_aprender"
               style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
               android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
               android:background="#00FFFFFF"
               android:src="@drawable/arrow_der"  />

       </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem. The problem was at my class of Dialog Fragment.

The line that was giving me the error was this one:

*getDialog().getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);*

That was what affected the whole dialog and moved the layout.